# gxp_wmsgetfeatureinfo GetFeatureInfo on a non-advertised layer possible?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, getfeatureinfo, boundless-suite

So, as the title states, I will like to know if it is possible to use gxp_wmscsource to send an GetFeatureInfo query to a non-advertised layer that was added to my opengeo SDK app using lazy loading.

I made my app and added a gxp_wmsgetfeatureinfo to it, but if a click over a non-advertised layer, the app doesn’t even sends a GET, I suppose it is because there is not a list of available layers...

I know it is possible to send a WMSGetFeatureInfo to a layer even if it is not advertised but I don’t know how to tell gxp_wmsgetfeatureinfo to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have

```
queryable: true
```

in your layer config.

Comment: Just found that out at the same time I was getting your answer. Thank you berry much anyway... I’ll like to have a list of all parameters you can set on the SDK plugins and widgets because  documentation gives only some examples...